# Scalacheck number generator between 0 <= x < 2^64

Tags: scala, scalacheck

I'm trying to right a good number generator that covers `uint64_t` in C. Here is what I have so far.

```
def uInt64s : Gen[BigInt] = Gen.choose(0,64).map(pow2(_) - 1)
```

It is a good start, but it only generates numbers `2^n - 1`. Is there a more effective way to generate random BigInts while preserving the number range `0 <= n < 2^64`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, maybe I am missing something here, but isn't it as simple as this?

```
def uInt64s : Gen[BigInt] = Gen.chooseNum(Long.MinValue,Long.MaxValue)
                               .map(x => BigInt(x) + BigInt(2).pow(63))
```

Longs already have the correct number of bits - just adding 2^63 so `Long.MinValue` becomes 0 and `Long.MaxValue` becomes 2^64 - 1. And doing the addition with `BigInt`s of course.

---

I was curious about the distribution of generated values. Apparently the distribution of `chooseNum` is not uniform, since it prefers special values, but the edge cases for Longs are probably also interesting for UInt64s:

```
/** Generates numbers within the given inclusive range, with
  *  extra weight on zero, +/- unity, both extremities, and any special
  *  numbers provided. The special numbers must lie within the given range,
  *  otherwise they won't be included. */
def chooseNum[T](minT: T, maxT: T, specials: T*)(
```

Comment: It does seem like this a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

With ScalaCheck...

Generating a number from 0..Long.MaxValue is easy.

Generating an unsigned long from 0..Long.MaxValue..2^64-1 is not so easy.

Tried:

❌ Gen.chooseNum(BigInt(0),BigInt(2).pow(64)-1) 
        **Does not work:** At this time there is not an implicit defined for BigInt.

❌ Arbitrary.arbBigInt.arbitrary 
       **Does not work:** It's type BigInt but still limited to the range of signed Long.

✔ Generate a Long as BigInt and shift left arbitrarily to make an UINT64 
       **Works:** Taking Rickard Nilsson's, ScalaCheck code as a guide this passed the test.

This is what I came up with:

```
// Generate a long and map to type BigInt
def genBigInt : Gen[BigInt] = Gen.chooseNum(0,Long.MaxValue) map (x => BigInt(x))

// Take genBigInt and shift-left a chooseNum(0,64) of positions
def genUInt64 : Gen[BigInt] = for { bi <- genBigInt; n <- Gen.chooseNum(0,64); x = (bi << n) if x >= 0 && x < BigInt(2).pow(64) } yield x

...

// Use the generator, genUInt64()
```

As noted, [Scalacheck number generator between 0 <= x < 2^64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37898802/scalacheck-number-generator-between-0-x-264/37901215#comment63495039_37901215), the distribution of the BigInts generated is not even. The preferred generator is @stholzm solution:

```
def genUInt64b : Gen[BigInt] =
  Gen.chooseNum(Long.MinValue,Long.MaxValue) map (x => 
    BigInt(x) + BigInt(2).pow(63))
```

it is simpler, the numbers fed to ScalaCheck will be more evenly distributed, it is faster, and it passes the tests.

Comment: For readability, i.e. as to the significance of the `"18..."` number, why not write `BigInt(2).pow(64)` rather than a `String`

Comment: So I copied your code verbatim and I got this error: `could not find implicit value for parameter num: Numeric[Any]`

Comment: If I change the `0` to `BigInt(0)` I get `could not find implicit value for parameter c: org.scalacheck.Gen.Choose[scala.math.BigInt]
`

Comment: I just went to Ricky Nils code, https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck, and I am afraid you are right. ChooseNum doesn't take a BigInt, so it won't work.  However, there is a chooseBigInt(), ahah. I'll change my answer in just a bit. :)

Comment: `Gen.chooseReallyBigInt` needs to be changed to `Arbitrary.arbBigInt.arbitrary`, that seems to work. When you change that I'll award you the answer

Comment: So this ended up being wrong, looking at the implementation details this only generates a number to `2^63-1`. Look at the implementation of `Arbitrary.argBigInt.arbitrary` https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/scalacheck/Arbitrary.scala#L171.

Comment: Summarized the comments into the answer (deleted my previous comments to clear the clutter).

Comment: Your final solution seems to generate numbers with different probabilities. Also, is `if x >= 0` really necessary?

Comment: No, the x>=0 is not necessary. Not sure what you mean by "different probabilities". I tested the generator using Specs2, it passes when checking the upper range, 2^63..2^64-1 as well as the lower

Comment: The arbitrary left shift skews the distribution of result values. The generator will only return odd numbers if `n` is 0, and it prefers powers of two. Not sure if it matters. The range seems to be correct though.

Comment: I see what you mean. I copied the technique from from rickynils Github code, he's the author of ScalaCheck, his code had n as the range of all signed Ints and then shifted arbitrarily from 32 to 128, testing what he called ReallyBigInt.

Comment: ReallyBigInt, hehe. I can only assume that the distribution in that case is supposed to prefer huge values. In this case it just seemed strange to me. Sorry for the downvote, I can only undo it if you edit your answer.

Comment: @stholzm, Thanks, for the thoughtful comments. I added a note to reflect your observations.

Comment: Thanks for comparing our different approaches! Was a pleasure discussing the solution with you.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler and more efficient alternative to [stholmz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38026967/2541573) is as follows:

```
val myGen = {
  val offset = -BigInt(Long.MinValue)
  Arbitrary.arbitrary[Long].map { BigInt(_) + offset }
}
```

1. Generate an arbitrary `Long`;
2. Convert it to a `BigInt`;
3. Add the appropriate offset, i.e. `-BigInt(Long.MinValue)`).

Tests in the REPL:

```
scala> myGen.sample
res0: Option[scala.math.BigInt] = Some(9223372036854775807)

scala> myGen.sample
res1: Option[scala.math.BigInt] = Some(12628207908230674671)

scala> myGen.sample
res2: Option[scala.math.BigInt] = Some(845964316914833060)

scala> myGen.sample
res3: Option[scala.math.BigInt] = Some(15120039215775627454)

scala> myGen.sample
res4: Option[scala.math.BigInt] = Some(0)

scala> myGen.sample
res5: Option[scala.math.BigInt] = Some(13652951502631572419)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have so far, I'm not entirely happy with it

```
  /**
    * Chooses a BigInt in the ranges of 0 <= bigInt < 2^^64
    * @return
    */
  def bigInts : Gen[BigInt] = for {
    bigInt <- Arbitrary.arbBigInt.arbitrary
    exponent <- Gen.choose(1,2)
  } yield bigInt.pow(exponent)

  def positiveBigInts : Gen[BigInt] = bigInts.filter(_ >= 0)

  def bigIntsUInt64Range : Gen[BigInt] = positiveBigInts.filter(_ < (BigInt(1) << 64))
  /**
    * Generates a number in the range 0 <= x < 2^^64
    * then wraps it in a UInt64
    * @return
    */
  def uInt64s : Gen[UInt64] = for {
    bigInt <- bigIntsUInt64Range
  } yield UInt64(bigInt)
```

Since it appears that `Arbitrary.argBigInt.arbitrary` is only ranges `-2^63 <= x <= 2^63` I take the `x^2` some of the time to get a number larger than `2^63`

Free free to comment if you see a place improvements can be made or a bug fixed

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but the distribution of generated values is not uniform. If I interpret this correctly, squares will appear more often than other numbers, because of the ^2. Also, it seems to be wasteful to generate numbers up to 2^126 before the filtering. *2 instead of ^2 should suffice. Or have a look at my answer.